# Inject only new records from filtered data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a filtered DE which generates some records with Opportunities I that I need to send updates about through a journey.

I have set the trigger/automation to evaluation only new records and only look at records after journey activation. However every time I run the filter automation which refreshes the DE and runs the journey, all the existing contacts are inserted again.

This is not a journey re-entry issue, as Contacts need to be able to enter more than once (for other Opportunities).

I've already tried creating a new version of the journey, but it's still not behaving as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's normal because refreshing a filtered DE is like an Overwrite. So after you run the refresh, JB considers all records in your DE as new.

Comment: What is the appropriate way to use the filtered DE in the Journey for new records? Ideally we don't want to use queries to generate the DE.

Comment: I can't think of any "simple" way of achieving this using filtered DE only. What I would do in this case is use a Standard DE which is populated using the filtered DE, then use this DE as an entry source on the journey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, this behavior is normal. **Refreshing** a filtered DE is like an **Overwrite**.

JB considers all records on your newly refreshed filtered DE as new and inject them all into the journey.

There is certainly many approches to get around this, but I'd suggest the following:

Use a standard DE that is identical to your filtered DE. You'll need a basic query that populates this DE after refreshing your filtered DE. 
This way you'll keep the history of already injected contacts to the journey, and  add new ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a date field filter so that your filter itself only pulls back new records.